# focus method on text box not actually sets the focus

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a strange behaviour here with focus method.
I Just want to understand why it is happening like this.

Case 1:
With the below code when I come out of last element i.e driveD hyperlink ,focus is not getting set to first text box even though I applied .focus() to first text box.

```js
function lastFocusOut() {
        alert('focus out ,setting focus to first text box');
        document.getElementById('nameId').focus();
    }
```

```css
input,a,button{
display:block;
margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <input id="nameId"   type="text" name="name"> <a href="c:\">drive</a>
        <input id="nameId1" type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="test" />
        <input type="text" name="name"> <a href="d:\">driveE</a> </form> <a href="d:\" onblur="lastFocusOut()">driveD</a> </body>
```

Case 2:
When I add a buttton after the last hyperlink It sets the focus back to first text box.

```js
function lastFocusOut() {
        alert('focus out ,setting focus to first text box');
        document.getElementById('nameId').focus();
    }
```

```css
input,a,button{
display:block;
margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <input id="nameId"    type="text" name="name"> <a href="c:\">drive</a>
        <input id="nameId1" type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="test" />
        <input type="text" name="name"> <a href="d:\">driveE</a> </form> 
        <a href="d:\" onblur="lastFocusOut()">driveD</a> </body>
        <button type ="submit" >Submit</button>
```

I want to understand two things here.

1)Why the focus is not getting set to first text box in case 1.

2)What really makes the difference just by adding the button at the end ,which is making the code work as expected.

Comment: I do get the alert message both times. You probably misunderstood that the popup happens on blur, a.k.a. when you click on something else but the link. Clicking the first link and then clicking your second example will execute blur of the first. The button has nothing to do with this. In your first example, click the link. Then click somewhere in the background. This makes `onblur` fire for me.

Comment: Agree with @PeterKrebs. Same `onblur` worked for me on both cases as well.